# How to access files downloaded on my windows machine from boot2docker?

Tags: windows, download, docker, boot2docker

I have a file which is downloaded from browser. I have boot2docker on my windows machine. From boot2docker, how can i access my downloaded file? Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

If you setup shared directories with VirtualBox, it is possible, however, it is overly complex for not much.

I'd advise to simply use `curl` or `wget` within boot2docker to download your file(s).

An other solution would be to use winscp to upload your file from windows to boot2docker.

Comment: Thanks creack. I tried curl and wget to install hadoop-0.20 on centOs 6. But unfortunately i can't able to do it. That's why i am trying alternative.

Comment: I don't know about 0.20, but here is a nice Dockerfile for 2.6.0, you probably can adapt for your targeted version: https://registry.hub.docker.com/u/sequenceiq/hadoop-docker/dockerfile/

Answer (score 0):

The download folder should be mounted in boot2docker already.

From [Boot2Docker's README](https://github.com/boot2docker/boot2docker#virtualbox-guest-additions):

> Alternatively, Boot2Docker includes the VirtualBox Guest Additions
>   built in for the express purpose of using VirtualBox folder sharing.
>
> The first of the following share names that exists (if any) will be
>   automatically mounted at the location specified:
>
> 1. `Users` share at `/Users`
> 2. `/Users` share at `/Users`
> 3. `c/Users` share at `/c/Users`
> 4. `/c/Users share at`/c/Users`
> 5. `c:/Users share at`/c/Users`

Since Windows' default download location is `C:\Users\[username]\Downloads` your downloaded file should be in the Boot2Docker VM at `/c/Users/[username]/Downloads`.